# putting print_r results in variable

Tags: php

In PHP I can say:

```
print_r($var);
```

What I can't do (at least I don't know how) is:

```
$var_info = print_r($var);
```

How can I accomplish the effect of putting the results of a `print_r` inside a variable?
PHP v5.3.5

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> When the second parameter is set to
>   TRUE, print_r() will return the
>   information rather than print it

```
$var_info = print_r($var,true);
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! quite easy!

Answer (score 6):

```
$var_info = print_r($var, true);
```