# How to Store WhatsApp PHP API Response in a Variable

Tags: php, xml, whatsapi

I am using the WhatsApp api with the link

https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation

From this tutorial, I am using the following code to receive the messages:

```
    $username = $get_list['userid'];
    $password = $get_list['password'];
    $nickname = ''; 
    $debug = "false";

    $w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
    try {
        $w->connect();
        $w->loginWithPassword($password);
        $w->sendMessage($username , '');
        $s = $w->pollMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Sorry ". $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I am getting the messages as follow :

```
tx  <stream:features>
tx    <readreceipts></readreceipts>
tx    <groups_v2></groups_v2>
tx    <privacy></privacy>
tx    <presence></presence>
tx  </stream:features>

tx  <auth mechanism="WAUTH-2" user="9195666669">����9195666669��/oNz|$%L�A#u)�1449637609</auth>

rx  <start from="s.whatsapp.net"></start>

rx  <stream:features></stream:features>

rx  <challenge>h�.� �z�It���_�*`�P</challenge>

tx  <response>����֖G�����C�NJ�qFz�o� #��NCve</response>

rx  <success t="1449637762" props="4" kind="free" status="active" creation="1449574308" expiration="1481110308">Ԕ��F��>����(�]I�</success>

tx  <presence name=""></presence>

tx  <message to="9195666669@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="458GQvvffv1so0" t="1449637610" notify="">
tx    <body></body>
tx  </message>

rx  <ib from="s.whatsapp.net">
rx    <offline count="0"></offline>
rx  </ib>

rx  <presence from="9195666669@s.whatsapp.net"></presence>

rx  <ack from="9195666669@s.whatsapp.net" class="message" id="458GdQvvfv1so0" t="1449637762"></ack>

rx  <presence from="9195666669@s.whatsapp.net" type="unavailable" last="1449637445"></presence>
```

I have not written any `print_r()` in the code then only it is printing the code. I don't want to print this code, and instead want to store it into a variable. How can I store it into a variable?

Comment: you are calling WhatsProt() class's function so it may be taht in these functions containing print_r() anywhere. You must to debug your code...

Comment: Hiii found the code with `print_r()` is only ` public function debugPrint($debugMsg)
    {
        if ($this->debug) {
            if (is_array($debugMsg) || is_object($debugMsg)) {
                print_r($debugMsg);

            }
            else {
                echo $debugMsg;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }`

Comment: Here's the source for the debugPrint function: https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/blob/494f7ccd43b16568cdb2ead8bcd92f705e3cd835/src/whatsprot.class.php

Answer (score 1):

If you had control over the code that calls `print_r`, then you could send the output directly to a variable: `$var_info = print_r($var,true);` - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762520/3012550

However, it seems you don't have control over the output, since the function definition [is part of the library](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/blob/494f7ccd43b16568cdb2ead8bcd92f705e3cd835/src/whatsprot.class.php) (line 1788). So, you can use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798178/3012550

```
ob_start();
functionThatCallsPrintR();
$output = ob_get_clean();
// $output contains everything outputed between ob_start() and ob_get_clean()
```